# scrollWidth and clientWidth always the same?

Tags: html, css, overflow

So I have a series of elements generated with ng-repeat that I've styled thusly:

```
.variable-content-size {
    max-height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 315px;
}
```

and I am using jquery to go through them to try to determine which of these has any content overflow. I found the same approach throughout S/O, which is basically to compare scrollWidth to clientWidth. If the former exceeds the latter, you know you have overflow. But for each element, they are always the same!! Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?...

```
<div class="variable-content-size">{{data.logs}}</div>/ <--this is an ng-repeated element
```

**UPDATE w/ JS:**

```
$.each($(".variable-content-size"), function (idx, el) {
      if (el.scrollWidth > el.clientWidth) {
          //do whatever in here.
      }
});
```

The if condition is never true. Even though the contents might be gigantic in some cases, and the styles I shared are definitely being applied such that the overflown content is cut off and ellipses are applied.

Comment: Can you provide the javascript and an example?

Comment: updated with javascript

Comment: looks like it's working to me https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xdYvWX

Comment: Weirdly enough, I just changed my max-width to 100 and now it's working!! I don't know why that mattered because the contents were being cutoff in both cases, but it did work! If anyone comes across this and can shed light, I'd be super appreciative. Thanks @MichaelCoker!

Comment: @spb i dunno, the example I did works with 315. Either way you need to give us a demo that reproduces the problem if you want help, otherwise we're just guessing.